# ProgressBar doesn't update while calling database

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've an issue with progress bar since it was not showing until the data is loaded.

I'm not sure whether my code is right or wrong. Please help on this issue and its cracking my head. Any suggestions would be really helpful for me plzzz..

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
progressBar1.Maximum = short.MaxValue;
progressBar1.Value = 0;

double value = 0;

UpdateProgressBarDelegate updatePbDelegate = new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(progressBar1.SetValue);

foreach (CDType ctp in dgAttributes.ItemsSource)
{
    if (ctp.IsSelected == true)
    {
        //Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        var CDTypeID = ctp.TYPE_ID;

        label3.Content = "Loading.." + CDTypeID;

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(conn.ConnectionString);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "LOAD_DATA_SOURCE_SAVE";

        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("CDTYPE_ID", CDTypeID);

        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

        do
        {
            value += 1;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(updatePbDelegate,
                              System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                              new object[] { ProgressBar.ValueProperty, value });                                          
            //i'm not sure whether its correct way or not to give below line here..? I mean execute non query...since it was looping all the time untill its reaches Maximum value
            //sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        while (progressBar1.Value != progressBar1.Maximum);

        sqlConnection.Close();
        //label3.Content = "Sucessfully Loaded..!";
    }
}
```

Comment: please fix the indentation. It's not that hard.

Comment: @user1990395 Are you loading your data in the UI thread?

Comment: Well... at first glance... do you really want your progress bar to run from 0 to 32767? This also might be a good example of using an "unknown" progress time as you're just hitting the database with no definitive start/end values or concept of "progress". See using a "marquee" style for your progress bar: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9e51ad57-988e-4c17-98f0-cd2a8abec503/ EDIT: Ooops, WPF, just use `IsIndeterminate`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.isindeterminate%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I've copied the text and not able to formatting the code and if I formatted it was deleting...

Comment: Hi Chris, Actually I really don't need the maximum time. Only I need for execution time of the stored proc and untill the data loads into database.

Comment: You haven't given us the context of this code. My guess is that *all* your code is running in the UI thread.

Comment: You need to show more code to get a proper answer. My guess is this is running off some UI event which means you are querying the database on the UI thread and tying it up. Your call to the `Dispatcher` is thus a waste of time.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery method will executing the storedproc and assume it will take 5 mins so I need to run the progressbar untill 5 mins

Comment: @user1990395 In that case, have your progress bar max value be the number of seconds (5 * 60) and consider using a background timer (like `System.Threading.Timer`) that runs every second and have it update your progress bar.

Comment: I was just calling the delegate --> UpdateProgressBarDelegate and Invoking this delegate based on progressbar maximum value

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've set up Timer and set that value into progressbar maximum value...Thanks a ton :-)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you cannot determine how long it will take you might want to use a progressbar with its style set to indeterminate.

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

If you use the UI thread to load the data the Progressbar might not update because the thread is busy. See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/2479bb5f-c8cd-4ec0-97db-7a15c8c2eeea) on how to fix that using a background worker to load the data. You can search on StackOverflow too; there are many questions on the backgroundworker.

If the database is passing data back in batches you could might be able to keep track of the number of batches on their way and use a progressbar with an actual value.